# How do I start inserting text between two methods, with spacing?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have this code:

```
01  int function1(){
02    //do something
03  }
04
05  int function2(){
06      //do something
07  }
```

And I want to insert a new function between function1 and function2.

Currently, I would put the cursor in line 03, press o, then Enter, so there's an empty line before, and another one after the line I'm editing.

Is there a simpler way? I do this often enough that I want to know if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

vim can edit key commands in any mode.
For example, Put in .vimrc:

```
imap <C-Enter> <Enter><C-W>
```

In insert mode, press Ctrl-Enter to avoid auto indentation when inserting a new line.

Or this:

```
nmap <C-Enter> o<Enter><C-W>
```

In normal mode, press Ctrl-Enter to simulate pressing o, then press enter, and finally remove the auto indentation.

Comment: Please prefer inoremap and nnoremap